# move & position an element under an existing sibling html element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to position a `<li>` to the exact same position as the last `<li>` on the page. I'm using the jQuery `.position()` function.

When you swipe left/drag to the left on my `<li>` after `1000ms` timeout I want to move the `<li>` to the position of my last `<li>` item `"stackPos"`

I setup the last element:

```
$('ul.feed li').last().addClass('stack');
```

Get it's position:

```
var stackPos = $('ul.feed li.stack').position();
```

Set the position after timeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $(this).css({top: stackPos.top, left: stackPos.left});
}, 1000);
```

After the timeout I can set a `console.log()` which fires but the position isn't updated.

Complete code & demo -
https://jsfiddle.net/myz3czro/32/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('ul.feed li').first().addClass('top');
$('ul.feed li').last().addClass('stack');    
var touch = $('ul.feed li.top').offset().left;
    var pullLeftLimit = touch - 15;
var stackPos = $('ul.feed li.stack').position();
console.log('Stack Of Cards at: ' + stackPos.left + ' top: ' + stackPos.top);

$($('.content ul li').get().reverse()).each(function(i, el) {
  $(el).css('z-index', i + 1);
  var degrees = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) - 10);
  $(el).css({
    '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',
    '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',  
    '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',  
    '-o-transform' : 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',  
    'transform' : 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',  
    'zoom' : 1
    });
});

$( function() {
  $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
    axis: "x",
    drag: function( event, ui ) {  
      var newTouch = $('ul.feed li.top').offset().left;

      if(pullLeftLimit > newTouch){
        $(this).addClass('swipe');
        setTimeout(function(){
          $(this).css({top: stackPos.top, left: stackPos.left});
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  });
});

$(function(){
  $( ".cover" ).on( "swipe", swipeHandler );   
  function swipeHandler( event ){
    $( this ).parent().addClass( "swipe" );
  }
});    

function stackMe(){
    console.log('test');
}

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a small mistake in the `setTimeout` function, but beside that, for a better performance I would choose the `draggable.stop` handler to process the card reposition.

At the end, the core reposition function looks like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      var self = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
        var stack = [];
        $(".content ul li").each(function(i, el) {
          stack.push($(el).css("z-index"));
        });
        stack.unshift(stack.pop());
        $(".content ul li").each(function(i, el) {
          $(el).css('z-index', stack[i]);
        });
        $(self).removeClass('swipe').css({
          top: stackPos.top,
          left: stackPos.left
        });
      }, 1000);
    },
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      var newTouch = $('ul.feed li.top').offset().left;
      if (pullLeftLimit > newTouch) {
        $(this).addClass('swipe');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

By using your card naming convention, the `z-index` will ROTATE then as follows:

```
Card a: z-index 5 --> will be 1
Card b: z-index 4 --> will be 5
Card c: z-index 3 --> will be 4
Card d: z-index 2 --> will be 3
Card e: z-index 1 --> will be 2
```

... and so on.